# DB structure for a photo application in MEAN. Is this a good approach?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, database

I'm new to MEAN and trying to get my feet wet with implementing an application. Basically I'm trying to make a photo app where each user can store photos.

My idea is to implement it as follows:

- Each user has a schema that has username, password and other basic credentials.
- Each uploaded photo will have a schema as:

  ```
  var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      photoFile: String,
      photoDescription: String
  });
  ```

`photoFile` contains the location where the file is stored.

- Then I will maintain another schema to track the photos:

  ```
  var photos = mongoose.Schema({
      username: String,
      photoObjects: [photoObject.id]
  });
  ```

So, is this a good structure to maintain photos of users using Mongo?
If not I'd appreciate some help in knowing what is wrong with this approach and how to improve it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you would accept my answer, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would add Last Updated and created.  Metadata never hurts in production applications and debug scenarios.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, I believe you should consider adding the photo schema to the user schema as an array and forget the complex and unwieldy mapping excersie this will require.

'var user = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String:

})'

http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/08/why-is-mongodb-wildly-popular/